# Changing sprite images with for loop

Tags: javascript

I've got a sprite of two images, one position is 0 0, another 0 -150 px. I'd like to make them change every 10 seconds. I'm vaguely familiar with JavaScript, so far I've got 
this:

```
function changeBackground () {
// some for loop? //

}
setInterval(function(){changeBackground()},10000);
```

I'm sorry this is realy just a few lines but I'm really lost. A little hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please show us the code where you need to swap the images

Comment: a better solution would be to use css3 so no javascript timer.

Comment: @cocco: OP wants to change the image every 10 seconds which is not possible with just CSS

Comment: @asifsid88 sure it's possible.. if you use sprites & keyframes.you just need to move the background image every 10 sec 150px

Comment: Sorry to say but what you are showing us is minimal effort, you should  try more stuff yourself. We could give you ananswer but you'll be back in 2 min with another questen. Anyway check the animate function of jQuery and callback function .

Comment: You just need to change the css class of your div/span that holds the sprite in your loop

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. This is untested, so there might be some errors, but you could solve it like this:

```
<div id="sprite"></div>

setBackgroundImage(frameNumber) {
    var style = document.getElementById('sprite').style;
    var pos;

    if (frameNumber === 0) {
        pos = 0;
    } else if (frameNumber === 1) {
        pos = -150;
    }

    style.backgroundPositionX = pos;
}

var currentFrame = 0;
function changeBackground () {
    currentFrame ++;
    currentFrame = currentFrame % 2;
    setBackgroundImage
}

setInterval(function(){changeBackground()},10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is help you if you need with animation please comment http://jsfiddle.net/hmZ7W/

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var oddEven = 1;
function changeBackground () {
    if(oddEven)
    {
        button.style.backgroundPosition = "0 150px";
        oddEven = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        button.style.backgroundPosition = "0 0";
        oddEven = 1;    
    }

}
setInterval(function(){changeBackground()},500);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this code for animation in JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        #sprite {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;              
            background: url(image.jpg) 0 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="main();">
    <script>

    var pos = [-10, -20, -30]; // image offset
    var posIdx = 0; // offset index

    function main() {
        var img = document.createElement('img')
        img.id = 'sprite';
        document.body.appendChild(img);

        setInterval(function() {
            anim(img);
        }, 1000);
    }

    function anim(el) {
        posIdx++;
        if (posIdx > pos.length - 1) posIdx = 0;
        el.style.backgroundPositionX = pos[posIdx] + 'px';
    }

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what i mean...

to support other browsers you need to add the other prefixes.(this works in chrome and safari)

NO javascript needed .. .especially NO timers.

your image is 'sprite.png' width 300px height 150px in this example

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<style>
div{
 width:150px;height:150px;
 background:url(sprite.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
 -webkit-animation:mymove 10s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes mymove{
0%{background-position:0px 0px;}
50%{background-position:0px 0px;}
51%{background-position:-150px 0px;}
100%{background-position:-150px 0px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

another way to don't use the javascript timer... is to change class on transition end.

so 2 classes every transition lasts 10sec.. and on end it swaps class.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<style>
div{
 width:150px;height:150px;
 background:url(sprite.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
 -webkit-transition:background-position 0s linear 10s;
}
div.odd{
 background-position:-150px 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<script>
window.onload=function(){
 var div=document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
 div.addEventListener('transitionend',function(){
  this.classList.toggle('odd');
 },false);
 div.classList.toggle('odd');// start the transition
}
</script>
<body>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```